# Infinite Scroll With Intersectionobserver & InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, webapi, intersection-observer

I'm trying to make an infinite scroll (without jQuery) to show more results in a page. I'm using an [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver) to detect a div called `#paginate` and everytime it enters the screen, the `#result` div will be refreshed.

```
var result = document.querySelector('#result');
var paginate = document.querySelector('#paginate');

var observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
if (entries.some(entry => entry.isIntersecting))
{
var pagination = 10;
fetch('/kernel/search.php?pagination='+pagination)
.then((response) => {
return response.text();
})
.then((html) => {
result.innerHTML = html;
});
}
});

observer.observe(paginate);
```

Here's the full code view with HTML:

```
<html>
<body>

<div class="row justify-content-sm-center justify-content-md-center justify-content-lg-center justify-content-xl-start no-gutters min-vw-100" id="result">
<div class="col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-9-result col-xl-4-result order-0">

<div class="card mx-3 mt-3">
<div class="card-body">
<a class="text-decoration-none" href="?topic=result-1">
<h5 class="card-title"> 
Result 1    
</h5>
</a>
<p class="card-text text-truncate"> 
Result 1 description.</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="card mx-3 mt-3">
<div class="card-body">
<a class="text-decoration-none" href="?topic=result-2">
<h5 class="card-title"> 
Result 2    
</h5>
</a>
<p class="card-text text-truncate"> 
Result 2 description.</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-light text-dark text-center border mx-3 my-3" id="paginate">
More results
</div>

</div>
</div>

<script>    
var result = document.querySelector('#result');
var paginate = document.querySelector('#paginate');

var observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
if (entries.some(entry => entry.isIntersecting))
{
var pagination = 10;
fetch('/kernel/search.php?pagination='+pagination)
.then((response) => {
return response.text();
})
.then((html) => {
result.innerHTML = html;
});
}
});

observer.observe(paginate);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It works, but it only works the first time and it doesn't refresh the `#result` div thereafter. I can see the `fetch` working in **Web Browser** > **Inspect** > **Network** tab, but there's no activity after the first refresh of the `#result` div meaning it doesn't detect the `#paginate` div anymore.

What's going on here? I assume it's because that I'm using an `innerHTML` and the `observer` somehow can't detect the `#paginate` div after the first refresh of the `#result` div. How can I solve this?

Comment: please add the relevant html code

Comment: @Guy Louzon: Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) and replaced it with [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

Because `innerHTML` seems to reset/forget `#paginate` after the first refresh of the `#result`, so the `observer` can't detect `#paginate` anymore to trigger the next `#result` refresh.

I could have used `innerHTML` with [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to do the same but `appendChild` adds a new `div` on each `#result` refresh, which I didn't really like.

As the solution, I'm inserting the refreshed `html` data before the beginning of `#paginate` without resetting/forgetting it's element `id` that's required for the `observer` to trigger the next `#result` refresh.

```
.then((html) => {
paginate.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', html);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it with jQuery and `.scroll` function and used ajax like this, maybe my code can help you and adapt it to your needs.

```
$('#customersList').scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight - 5000) {
        // Do your stuff here.
        getCustomers();
    }
})


function getCustomers(){
    let $customerList = $('#customersList');
    let offset        = ($customerList.attr('data-offset')) ? 
    
    $customerList.attr('data-offset') : 0;

    if ($customerList.data('requestRunning')) {
        return;
    }
    $customerList.data('requestRunning', true);

    return $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  data: {offset: offset},
                  url : routes.routes.customers.get
              })
        .done(function (data) {
            let _htmlCustomersList = ($customerList.is(':empty')) ? '' : $customerList.html();
            let response           = data.data;
            
            if (response) {
                for (const i in response) {
                    let v = JSON.parse(response[i]);
                    _htmlCustomersList += '<div class="client-group edit" data-id="' + v['id'] + '"></div><hr>';
                }

                offset = parseInt(offset) + 200;
                $customerList.attr('data-offset', offset).html(_htmlCustomersList);
            }
        })
        .always(function () {
            $customerList.data('requestRunning', false);
        });

}
```

my getCustomer function runs before reaching the end of the page and loads 200 more items each time.

I hope this can help you a little bit

Comment: I don't want to use jQuery, just pure JavaScript and newest Web API features.

Comment: Yes, I thought it might help you a bit.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are removing `#paginate` after the first update, because it is in the `#result`.

Please, use indentation :)

Comment: Yes, it's in `#result` and `#paginate` doesn't get removed. I can see `#paginate` on the bottom of the page after the first `fetch` refresh, but it doesn't trigger the `observer` at all.

Answer (score 0):

The #result div is the main wrapper of the content
using innerHTML to update the contents of the div, will result in replacing the entire content inside of the div...

Beyond the fact that innerHTML is absolute, and erases any DOM objects (and their events) hence bad practice, it's not that good solution either, since you'd like to append rather then replace the data, upon scrolling

I would suggest to add a div above the paginate, which will hold the added data, something like:

```
...
<div id="result"></div>
<div class="alert alert-light text-dark text-center border mx-3 my-3" id="paginate">
More results
</div>
```

Then use some sort of appending, for the content added
so something like:

```
.then((html) => {
let res = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/xml");
document.getElementById("result").appendChild(res);
});
```

Hope that helps

Comment: There's no need to listen to an `onscroll` event, the `IntersectionObserver` does it and works for me. So can you tell me how can I do `result.innerHTML = html;` with `node.appendChild()`?

Comment: As I answered, I didn't see where the result node appears in the code

Comment: an examplw for append child: https://www.w3schools.com /jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

Comment: yes. I don't see what's selected, and what's added to it

Comment: `#result` div is there in the HTML code, use the horizontal scroll because the code is overflown. The `<div>`s with `card` classes are the results inside the `#result` div, and there are many results. I have only included 2 results here. And lastly there is the `#paginate` div, which is also inside the `#result` div. As soon as the scroll reaches `#paginate` div, the `#result` div should refresh. Right now it only works the first time and JavaScript can't detect the `#paginate` div thereafter even though I can see the `#paginate` div on the page.

Comment: my answer as to add a childnode is even better. let me fix my answer a bit